# How to autofil otp using pinput flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

Im using the pinput flutter package for otp verification .
the otp autofil not working in my code.I tried adding the androidsmsautofill method,
Please help me fix the issue..
Attached my code

```
               Pinput(
                  focusNode: focusNode,
                  androidSmsAutofillMethod:
                      AndroidSmsAutofillMethod.smsRetrieverApi,
                  length: 6,
                  defaultPinTheme: defaultPinTheme,
                  listenForMultipleSmsOnAndroid: true,
                  controller: _pinPutController                   
                  onChanged: ((value) => print(value)),
                  onCompleted: (pin) async {
                    try {
                      await FirebaseAuth.instance
                          .signInWithCredential(
                              PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                                  verificationId: _verificationCode!,
                                  smsCode: pin))
                          .then((value) async {
                        if (value.user != null) {
                          SharedPrefs sp = SharedPrefs();
                          sp.saveFirebaseUser(value.user!.uid);

                          Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
                              (route) => false);
                        }
                      });
                    } catch (e) {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          SnackBar(content: Text(e.toString())));
                    }
                  },
                ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `firebase_auth` you don't need to use `smsRetrieverApi` because `firebase_auth` support automatic SMS code resolution. you have just to obtain OTP from firebase and set it via TextEditingController

Try something like this:

```
final pinController = TextEditingController();
Widget _pinput (){
  return Pinput(controller: pinController);
}

await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
  phoneNumber: '+44 8569 459 321',
  verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
     pinController.setText(credential.smsCode); 
  },
);
```